# Increasing the range of an RF module

Tags: lora, lorawan

I am working with a [RF-LORA-SO 868Mhz module.](https://www.rfsolutions.co.uk/radio-modules-c10/frequency-c57/fm-lora-transceiver-module-pre-set-to-868mhz-p468)

I read [this article](https://www.rs-online.com/designspark/rf-lora-the-50km-radio-module) that says the range of this module could go up to 50km. But I would need to connect an antenna to my LoRa module. This article I mentioned above doesn't seem to talk much about wiring.

Most of these antennas have SMA.

How do I connect an antenna like this to my radio module?

[image: antenna]

Comment: Hi Haziq, it seems that the module you're using and the antenna you posted are the same than in the article you linked—which contains diagrams showing the necessary connections. Thus, the connectivity questions is unclear. Furthermore the product description you posted lists 16km as range so you probably need the antenna to get a longer distance. Considering that both questions you pose seem answered in your links it's unclear to me what you want to know. That's why I'm putting the question on hold. If you want to clarify you can [edit] your question.

Comment: Unless the question is expanded, it is going to be hard to add much detail to the answers. The basic question you ask is trivially obvious, until you explain exactly where you are lost.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data sheet is not too forthcoming on their expectation for connecting an antenna (other than suggesting that a matching network is mandatory if you run high power). However, from the photos in the linked article, it's clear that what was used in this example was a 50 ohm coax to SMA 'pigtail'. You can get a short coax pre-connected to an SMA (with maybe a 2nd connector on the other end which you can cut). Keep the bare wires at the end of the coax where it solders on to the module as short as possible and take care not to melt the insulation (heatsink with pliers).

You shouldn't expect optimum performance like this, unless you're lucky (but it may be close).

The quoted 50km range seems to be in free-space, to an aircraft. On the ground, you will experience attenuation and reflection (trees, buildings, etc) and these can have a huge impact on range. This goes some way to explaining the difference between the module's data-sheet performance, and the best-case that can be achieved in perfect conditions.

You can also sometimes get increased range by using a more directional antenna. This rapidly becomes much more specialist though. I don't know what the LoRa protocol assumes, but radio protocols typically make some assumptions about time-of-flight in a duplex system, and this can also hard-limit the achievable range.